# Xgboost 回帰でエラーが発生する

Tags: r

以下のコードを実行したところ、エラーが発生してしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) でエラー: 
  [23:11:58] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cu:61: Check failed: preds.Size() == info.labels_.Size() (75 vs. 25) :  labels are not correctly providedpreds.size=75, label.size=25, Loss: reg:squarederror
```

**現状のコード**

```
#databaseの読み込み
database<-read.csv("database.csv")

database

#databaseのAtmosphereを質的変数に変換
database$Atmosphere<-as.factor(database$Atmosphere)

database

#csvファイルからdata.tableへ変換
dt<-data.table(database,keep.rownames=F)

dt

#学習データの抽出
train.data=dt[1:25,]

#検証データの抽出
test.data=dt[26:39]

#学習データの説明変数(Hydrogen.content以外)をmodel.mx_evとして抽出
model.mx_ev<-sparse.model.matrix(Hydrogen.content~.,train.data)

model.mx_ev

#学習データの目的変数をmodel.mx_ovとして抽出
model.mx_ov<-xgb.DMatrix(model.mx_ev,label=train.data$Hydrogen.content)

model.mx_ov

#検証データの説明変数(Hydrogen.content以外)をpred.mx_evとして抽出
pred.mx_ev<-sparse.model.matrix(Hydrogen.content~.,test.data)

pred.mx_ev

#検証データの目的変数をmodel.mx_ovとして抽出
pred.mx_ov<-xgb.DMatrix(pred.mx_ev,label=test.data$Hydrogen.content)

pred.mx_ov

#パラメーター調整(デフォルト)#
params <- list(
  eta=0.3,
  gamma=0,
  max_depth=6,
  min_child_weight=1,
  max_delta_step=0,
  subsample=1,
  colsample_bytree=1,
  colsample_bylevel=1,
  lambda=1,
  alpha=0
)

#Xgboost学習#
xgb<- xgboost(data=model.mx_ev,label=train.data$Hydrogen.content, num_class=3, objective="reg:linear", booster="gbtree", nrounds=100, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_class = 3` という引数を消してください. これは分類のクラス数を指定する引数で, 回帰には使いません.

例:

```r
data(iris)
iris <- rename(iris, Hydrogen.content = Sepal.Length)

require(xgboost)
require(data.table)
require(Matrix)

dt <- data.table(iris, keep.rownames = F)
dt <- iris

#学習データの抽出
train.data <- dt[1:25, ]

#検証データの抽出
test.data <- dt[26:39, ]

#学習データの説明変数(Hydrogen.content以外)をmodel.mx_evとして抽出
model.mx_ev <- sparse.model.matrix(Hydrogen.content ~ ., train.data)

xgb <- xgboost(data = model.mx_ev, label = train.data$Hydrogen.content, objective = "reg:linear", nrounds = 100)
```

なお, もし本当にやりたいのが回帰ではなく分類だった場合, `objective=` のほうを変更することになります.